# Can I add to a class definition from inside a module?

Tags: ruby, class, ruby-on-rails-3, module

I have a method I want to add to a class in a Rails app. I tried to separate it out into a module, like so:

```
module Hah
  class String
    def hurp
      "hurp durp"
    end
  end
end
#make sure the file containing the module is loaded correctly.
puts "Yup, we loaded"

#separate file
include Hah
"foobar".hurp
#should be "hurp durp"
```

I know the file containing the module is being loaded correctly because the `puts` prints correctly when I include the file, but I get an error:

```
undefined method `hurp' for "foobar":String
```

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module Hah
  class String
    #...
  end
end
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
class Hah::String
  #...
end
```

which makes a class `Hah::String` and does not refer to the class `String` in the global namespace. Note that the latter only works if `module Hah` was already declared (with the `module` keyword, `Module.new`, etc), while the former declares or re-opens `module Hah` and then within that scope declares or re-opens `class String` which, in context, is implicitly `class Hah::String`.

To open the class `String` in the global namespace, use:

```
module Hah
  class ::String
    #...
  end
end
```

because `::String` references the class `String` strictly in the top level / global namespace.

Comment: Whoa. Lots of new things to me in this answer (which solved my problem btw). So a module creates a new namespace, and :: is the scope resolution operator, and ::<something> refers to <something> in the global namespace?

Comment: @Jergason: And classes are also modules, and thus also create namespaces. (Actually, classes and modules are really just objects assigned to constants. So, modules and classes act as namespaces for constants.)